# How to remove duplicate devices in bluetooth connection using GKPeerPickerController in ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gksession, gkpeerpickercontroller

I want to connect two ios devices via bluetooth using GKPeerPickerController.
At the first time, it connects well but after that there is a problem in connction on can't connected.

There are duplicate devices listing in GKPeerPickerController alert while searching near by devices. Please help me.

I am using following code to search nearby devices via bluetooth.

```
#pragma mark - GameKit Peer Picker
-(void)startSearch { GKPeerPickerController *picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init]; picker.delegate = self; [picker show]; }

-(void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker{picker.delegate = nil;}

-(GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {
   NSString *sessionIDString = @"MTBluetoothSessionID";
  return [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionIDString displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer]; 
}

-(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *)session {}
```

Comment: Would be better if you described the error in more detail and the way you use the APIs.

Comment: I am using GameKit.framework.

Comment: That's clear, but what is the error?

Comment: When i connect to device from list at first time, connects successfully but after dismissing or canceling picker alert then again searching device, there are duplicate devices in the list. I want unique or filtered device list in picker alert.

Comment: Hi Nicks you got any solution, I,m too facing this kind of issue!